# Kotlin / lateinit property binding has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I working on Quiz App from YT tutorial and I am facing the issue with **lateinit property binding has not been initialized**.

Here its the part where i have initialized binding, i get error in bolded words: binding = **MessageItemBinding**.inflate(**inflater**)

**Code part**

```
class QuizQuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityQuizQuestionBinding
private var mCurrentPosition: Int = 1 // Default and the first question position
private var mQuestionsList: ArrayList<Question>? = null
private var mSelectedOptionPosition: Int = 0
private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0

private var mUserName: String? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.message_item, container, false)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question)

    mUserName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)

    mQuestionsList = Constants.getQuestions()

    setQuestion()

    binding.tvOptionOne.setOnClickListener(this)
    ...
}
```

Here's my graddle. Maybe you would what's missing

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
...

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

...

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.0.0-rc1'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly setting up the binding I assume. The following code seems the issue

```kotlin
  binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.message_item, container, false)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question)
```

Instead you can simply let it be like this. You are currently setting up binding of some other layout to your activity.

```kotlin
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_quiz_question)
```

Refer here for more:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Comment: Thank you for the help @che10 , but i doesn't recognize 'DataBindingUtil' the reference in 'DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_quiz_question)' , maybe i am missing dependency or something?

Comment: Check if your DataBinding is enabled in gradle and your XML is setup properly.

Comment: I did enabled DataBinding, but i haven't  showed in here, yes probably is something wrong with XML  as most of the time was pushing 'com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout' and when i changed gradle it started pushing this 'lateinit error'. What a mess :/